# How to return a docker stream through unirest client

Tags: java, unirest

I have the following code: 
public Future> getAsyncResponse(final Map queryParams) {

```
    GetRequest request = Unirest.get(url);
    // add any extra headers if so sent in for the request
    request = request.headers(headers);

    // Add any extra request parameters if any required for the request.
    request = (GetRequest) addRequestParams(request, queryParams);
    System.out.println(request.getUrl()); // NOPMD let the URL get printed out on the console
    return request.asStringAsync();
}
```

1. But the call getAsyncResponse(params).get() waits for the entire task to complete then returns the HttpResponse object
2. we can use HttpResponse.getRawBody() to get the stream but its not real time.

Can anyone help me here in getting a real time stream through unirest.???